# Vim outdenting javascript

Tags: javascript, vim

I'm having an issue with javascript indenting/outdenting. I've searched around online and in stackoverflow. I've found a lot of answers about indenting, but it doesn't look like any of them are the same issue I'm having.

When I try to add a property to an object where the property is an array or an object **and** the new property follows another property that is an object, the new property and it's brackets are outdented to the beginning of the file.

E.g.:

```
Ext.define('FeedReader.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    requires: [
        'FeedReader.view.main.MainController',
        'FeedReader.view.main.MainModel'
    ],
    xtype: 'app-main',

    // If I add the `items` found below up here, the indenting is fine

    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'main'
    },
    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },

// If I add the `items` property here, the following outdenting occurs
items:[

]

...the rest of the object
```

The outdenting happens as soon as I create the newline between the newly created property's brackets.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

## EDIT

Here's my .vimrc if it helps. Sorry it's sloppy!

```
call pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin on

set t_Co=256 

set encoding=utf-8
" Prevents the hiding of double quotes in json formatted files.
set conceallevel=0

hi clear SpellBad
hi SpellBad cterm=underline,bold ctermfg=white ctermbg=red

set relativenumber
set number

set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set autoindent
set smartindent
set nowrap
set hlsearch
set backspace=indent,eol,start "Allow backspace to work like most other apps, e.g. deleting a line ending will take you to the previous line

set backupdir=~/vim_backups
set swapfile
set dir=~/vim_swaps
set showmode
set mouse=nicr
set laststatus=2

" Setting character to use for showing indents in indentLine bundle
let g:indentLine_char = '|'
let g:indentLine_color_term = 236


" NerdTree specific configs
let NERDTreeShowHidden=1


" Setting the path so we can use the :find command
set path=$PWD/**

" Function Key Mappings ===============================================

"F2

" Toggle spell check
:map <F2> :setlocal spell! spelllang=en_us<CR>

" Toggle spell check in insert mode
":imap <F2> <Esc>:setlocal spell! spelllang=en_us<CR>i
inoremap <F2> <C-\><C-O>:setlocal spelllang=en_us spell! spell?<CR>

"F3

" Underline the current line with dashes in normal mode
nnoremap <F3> yyp<c-v>$r-

" Underline the current line with dashes in insert mode
inoremap <F3> <Esc>yyp<c-v>$r-A

"F4

" Double Underline the current line with dashes in normal mode
nnoremap <F4> yyp<c-v>$r=

" Double Underline the current line with dashes in insert mode
inoremap <F4> <Esc>yyp<c-v>$r=A

" Control Key Mappings ===============================================

" CTRL-h

" ctrl+c to toggle highlight.
let hlstate=0
nnoremap <c-h> :if (hlstate%2 == 0) \| nohlsearch \| else \| set hlsearch \| endif \| let hlstate=hlstate+1<cr>

" CTRL-n

" Toggle NerdTree 
map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" CTRL-l

" Toggle NerdTree 
map <C-l> :! clear ; php -l %<CR>

" Smooth the scrolling for ctrl-e, ctrl-y, and mouse wheel
map <C-U> <C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y>                                                                                          |
map <C-D> <C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E>

" Moving entire lines up and down
map <C-UP> ddkP
map <C-DOWN> ddp

inoremap <C-UP> <ESC>ddkPi
inoremap <C-DOWN> <ESC>ddpi

" Insert empty lines without going into insert mode
" Enter = line below, Shift Enter = line above
nmap <S-Return> O<Esc>
nmap <CR> o<Esc>

"Start tabular command
vmap <S-t> :Tab /

"Control P buffer only
noremap <C-b> :CtrlPBuffer<CR>

" Highlight all instances of pattern on double click:
:map <2-LeftMouse> *


"Enable powerline symbols for airline
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

" suppress syntax errors for html when working with ember. 
let g:syntastic_mode_map={ 'mode': 'active',
                     \ 'active_filetypes': [],
                     \ 'passive_filetypes': ['html'] }
```

Also, when grabbing my vimrc I remembered that I do have pathegon installed, so here's the list of bundles I'm using (pulled from listing my ~/.vim/bundles/ dir):

- Vundle.vim
- ack
- command-t
- ctrlp.vim
- indentLine
- nerdtree
- syntastic
- tabular
- vim-airline
- vim-colors-solarized
- vim-javascript
- vim-surround

Answer (score 0):

I did your code in my vim terminal and did not have this problem. Can you maybe do a gist of your .vimrc to see if there is anything in there that might be causing this issue?

I am not sure about indentLine but see if adding this helps for formatoptions:

```
set formatoptions=crnqn1j
```

I am still learning about all the options for formatting but this might be a good start if that helps for you. I will also take a look at the indentLine plugin and see if I find anything.

Comment: perfect. I will then take a look and try to help out

Comment: The only one that I saw that could cause a problem would have been vim-javascript but I added that bundle to my bundles and still did not cause a problem. I use YADR so I am not sure if there is a setting in there that has made a difference between yours and mine. Let me add my .vimrc and you can compare. One moment

Comment: Here is my .vimrc if you want to compare and see if there is anything that helps you: https://gist.github.com/e6b0cabf62c2283d758b.git

Comment: Cool, I'll give the setting in your answer a try and check out your vimrc. I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately the setting didn't work. Also, I'm getting a 404 on your vimrc link. Is the path protected or maybe an incorrect link?

Comment: Awesome thanks. I can't dig into it now, but I'll look over it tonight.